# jruby rails : Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am trying to compile my javascript assets. i have included plotly.js file which is almost 2MB in size. also i have included angualr2.dev.js file which is again 1MB in size.

whenever i am compiling my assets using command `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` i am getting below error.

```
Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.<init>(org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray.jav
a:66)
org.mozilla.javascript.Context.newArray(org/mozilla/javascript/Context.java:1626
)
org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newArrayLiteral(org/mozilla/javascript/Scri
ptRuntime.java:3733)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpre
ter.java:1776)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpreter.
java:815)
org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpret
edFunction.java:109)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(org/mozilla/javascript/Native
Array.java:1635)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray
.java:330)
org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(org/mozilla/javascript/IdFunctionOb
ject.java:97)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpre
ter.java:1479)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpreter.
java:815)
org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpret
edFunction.java:109)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(org/mozilla/javascript/Native
Array.java:1635)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray
.java:330)
org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(org/mozilla/javascript/IdFunctionOb
ject.java:97)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpre
ter.java:1479)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpreter.
java:815)
org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpret
edFunction.java:109)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(org/mozilla/javascript/Native
Array.java:1635)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray
.java:330)
org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(org/mozilla/javascript/IdFunctionOb
ject.java:97)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpre
ter.java:1479)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpreter.
java:815)
org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpret
edFunction.java:109)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(org/mozilla/javascript/Native
Array.java:1635)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray
.java:330)
org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(org/mozilla/javascript/IdFunctionOb
ject.java:97)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpre
ter.java:1479)
org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpreter.
java:815)
org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpret
edFunction.java:109)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(org/mozilla/javascript/Native
Array.java:1635)
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray
.java:330)
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How i can resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try pre-compiling using an alternate ExecJS runtime (e.g. having `node` installed)

... instead of `gem 'therubyrhino'`

Comment: i tried rake assets:precompile EXECJS_RUNTIME='Node' JRUBY_OPTS="-J-d32 -X-C"  and it worked for me .. thanks